# super class android life cycle

Tags: android, lifecycle

Why is it that you need to call the super class in the android lifecycle? For example, in onCreate you need to call super.onCreate, or onDestroy super.onDestroy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It makes sure that any relevant lifecycle management code across the full class hierarchy gets invoked.

If you have `MyBaseActivity` that extends `Activity`, and `MySpecificActivity` that extends `MyBaseActivity`, calling through to the lifecycle methods in the superclass at each level means `MyBaseActivity` will still be able to respond to lifecycle events.

Comment: Thanks. What do you mean by "still be able to respond to lifecycle events"?

Comment: If superclass A has a method `foo()`, and subclass B of A overrides `foo()`, the code contained in `A#foo()` will not be run when `foo()` is invoked on an instance of class B unless `B#foo()` calls `super.foo();`.

Comment: `A.foo()` has code (like tidying resource code) that `B.foo()` won't do unless `B.foo()` calls `super.foo();`